# Неожиданное взаимодействие canvas c элементами "relative"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, canvas

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста советом или источником, где найти информацию по проблеме, а проблема состоит в следующем:
Есть задача создать скрипт для шахматной доски. Все довольно-таки просто, иметь возможность перетаскивать шахматы на доску. Это сделано. Также задачка гласит, что нужно иметь возможность рисовать стрелочки - что-то типа маршрута шахмат и сделать это нужно средствами html,css и js, после чего сохранить в виде изображения эту доску. Вот тут и возникла затыка. Делаю сохранение следующим образом:

```js
$('#saveImage').on('click',function(){
    html2canvas($('.game'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            newCanvas.setAttribute('width',700);
            newCanvas.setAttribute('height',700);
            var ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height,0,0,700,700);
            var dataURL = newCanvas.toDataURL();
            var img = $(document.createElement('img'));
            img.attr('src', dataURL);
            $('#download').attr('href', newCanvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
            $('#download').attr('download','new file.png');
            $('#download')[0].click();
        }
    });
});
```

Само сохранение работает, но в виду того что стрелочки сделаны самым костыльным, по моему мнению, методом из всех возможных, в виду того, что другого выхода не нашел. Происходит это так:

```css
.arrow{
    height: 5px;
    width: 40px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    transform: rotate(-50deg);
    cursor: pointer;}
#arrowHead{
    width: 5px !important;
    height: 3px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 800;
    float: left; 
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: green;}
#arrowBody{
    width: 33px;
    height: 3px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 2.5px;
    left: 2px;}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="arrow">
    <div id="arrowBody"></div>
    <div id="arrowHead" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></div>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что при сохранении изображения, стрелочки теряют свою форму и выглядят не совсем как стрелочки. 
Ниже то что получается сохранить, из сanvas:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так должно быть на самом деле, по крайней мере мне этого очень хотелось бы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите, возможно я что-то делаю совсем не так или есть методы обойти эту проблему ибо все элементы, у которых статическое позиционирование отображаются нормально.
Буду благодарен за любую информацию. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Трансформы не подерживаются этим плагином:

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/220

Вам нужно искать способ нарисовать стрелки без `transform: rotate`.

Например, нарисовать стрелки прямо на `canvas`:

```js
function canvas_arrow(context, fromx, fromy, tox, toy){
    var headlen = 15;   // длина стрелок
    var angle = Math.atan2(toy-fromy,tox-fromx);
    
    context.moveTo(fromx, fromy);
    context.lineTo(tox, toy);
    context.moveTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle-Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle-Math.PI/6));
    context.moveTo(tox, toy);
    context.lineTo(tox-headlen*Math.cos(angle+Math.PI/6),toy-headlen*Math.sin(angle+Math.PI/6));
}

ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
canvas_arrow(ctx,10,90,90,10);// функция, рисующая стрелку, описана выше
ctx.lineWidth=3;// ширина линий
ctx.strokeStyle="#005500";// цвет линий
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id='c' width="100" height="100">
```

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, как тогда сделать так, чтобы canvas не заслонял шахматную доску и в то же время, стрелочки можно было рисовать. Так как сейчас или canvas заслоняет доску и ее не видно, или доска полностью скрывает стрелку с canvas, если использовать z-index...

Comment: Возможно ли это вообще или я в тупике и нужно искать альтернативу?

Answer (score 0):

Неделю думаю над подобной проблемой (начинающий программист-любитель), пока не придумал ничего лучше, как сделать 3 слоя:

1. основная сетка (у меня div'ы) + картинки;
2. канвас
3. прозрачная сетка из div'ов, которые точно совпадают с 1 слоем.

Обернулось все еще в div, для позиционирования и трансформаций.

П.С. это ответ на вопрос ниже.